# Is there a way to combine an observable with an object?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Is there a way to combine an observable with an object that is not an observable in JavaScript?

If not, what about adding data to the observable?

Comment: Combine an Object with an `Observable` or with the data passing through an `Observable`? Could you add some code (even pseudo) of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please provide a bit more detail. Combine in what way? Please give an example of the kind of thing you would like to do.

Comment: So there is an observable. There is data related to an object in that observable that I need to pull from somewhere else but it's not an observable. Is there a way to add that data to that observable?
For example, there is an observable containing object animal = {dog: {legs: 4}, duck: {legs: 2}}. I'd like to add another key-value pair like so {dog:{legs: 4, furry: true}, duck: {legs:2, furry:false}} but furry:true and furry:false are not data that comes from another observable. Is this possible?

Comment: you can use the map operator: myObs.map(addFurryProp) where addFurryProp is the function to transform the animal object. And I hate the fact that duck is not furry :)) a furry duck would be so cute